# How to create data frame if Excel file is my source file in databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-excel

I have an Excel file as source file and I want to read data from Excel file and convert data in DataFrame using Databricks. I am new in Scala.

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
.option("location", "/FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx") 
.option("useHeader","true")
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false") 
.option("inferSchema","false")
.option("addColorColumns", "false") 
.load("/FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the available Excel plugin:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.8.2"
```

Follow the samples from https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel to build your Dataframe.

Comment: I have added maven library in my work space, I loaded my excel file in databricks HDFs and now i am trying to  read excel file but it is showing error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx (No such file or directory) .

Comment: Update your question and add your code. You can include the stacktrace to see what could be the problem.

Comment: code : val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("location", "/FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx")
    .option("useHeader", "true")
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("addColorColumns", "false")
    .load("/FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx")                                                                            
Error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx (No such file or directory) but file is present.

Comment: Your spark executor is trying to load this file from a local storage... where is exactly your file stored?

Comment: my file is present at this location(/FileStore/tables/Airline.xlsx) but still getting error. File path is correct.

Comment: Yo should have a stack trace to see what type of file system provider is using your executor. I mean, if you are executing Spark in your computer with a master pointing to your localhost it would use local "POSIX". But if you performs spark submit to one cloud provider it will use another, for example a hdfs conector or s3. If you are using Databricks maybe you must put dbfs:// as protocol.

Comment: i got solution for this issue we should use latest maven library for same.libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.11.1"